# What are the best Pre-Processing techniques for Sentiment Analysis.?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, lightgbm

I am trying to classify a dataset of reviews in to two classes say class A and class B. I am using `LightGBM` to classify.

I have changed the parameters for the classifier many times but I can't get a huge difference in the results.

I think the problem is with the pre-processing step. I defined a function as shown below to take care of pre-processing. I used `Stemming` and removed `stopwords`. I don't know what I am missing. I have tried `LancasterStemmer` and `PorterStemmer`

```
stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
def cleanData(text, lowercase = False, remove_stops = False, stemming = False, lemm = False):
    txt = str(text)
    txt = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\s]',r'',txt)
    txt = re.sub(r'\n',r' ',txt)

    if lowercase:
        txt = " ".join([w.lower() for w in txt.split()])

    if remove_stops:
        txt = " ".join([w for w in txt.split() if w not in stops])

    if stemming:
        st = PorterStemmer()
        txt = " ".join([st.stem(w) for w in txt.split()])

    if lemm:
        wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        txt = " ".join([wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in txt.split()])
    return txt
```

**Are there any more pre-processing steps to be done to get a better accuracy.?**

URL for the dataset : [Dataset](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/predict-the-happiness/predict-the-happiness/f2c2f440-8-dataset_he.zip)

**EDIT :**

Parameters that I used are as mentioned below.

```
params = {'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'binary',
    'metric': 'binary_logloss',
    'learning_rate': 0.01, 
    'max_depth': 22, 
    'num_leaves': 78,
    'feature_fraction': 0.1, 
    'bagging_fraction': 0.4, 
    'bagging_freq': 1}
```

I have altered the `depth` and `num_leaves` parameters along with others. But the accuracy is kind of stuck at a certain level..

Comment: Are any terms with negative implications (like "not") in your list of stopwords?

Comment: Are you sure it's about the pre-processing, it seems ok to me ? How many words do you use to build your input vector, 1 word vector, 2 words vector, 3...,  ? What is the dataset and the labels ? Did you compare your results with other tries, if the dataset is public ?

Comment: Its for a competition. Dataset is public. I will edit question with the URL for the dataset. My result is about 2% less in terms of accuracy of the best result yet..

Comment: I think its about preprocessing. I have run almost all combinations for parameters.!!

Comment: Now I have tried `WordNetLemmatizer` and I have got an increase of 1% in accuracy.!!. I will try parameter tuning again and let you know the results.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider. First of all your training set is not balanced - the class distribution is ~ 70%/30%. You need to consider this fact in training. What types of features are you using? Using the right set of features could improve your performance.

Comment: Yes, training data is not balanced. I used `LightGBM` for classification. I will post parameters used in the edit.!!

Comment: Any suggestion on how to handle imbalance.?

Comment: You can try SMOTE or one sided sampling.